# Difference between BFMatcher and FlannBasedMatcher

Tags: opencv

I would like to know what is the difference in term of precision or quality of the matches between the `BFMatcher` and `FlannBasedMatcher` in openCV. I know the `FlannBasedMatcher` might be faster when applied to a large data base but are the two matcher going to find the same matches at the end regardless of the time of execution?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

BFMatcher is going to try all the possibilities (which is the meaning of "**Brute Force**" and hence it will find the best matches.

FLANN, meaning "**Fast Library for Approximate Nearest Neighbors**", will be much faster but will find an approximate nearest neighbors. It will find a good matching, but not necessarily the best possible one. You can play with FLANN's parameters in order to increase the precision (i.e. the "quality" of the matchings), but it will be at the cost of slowing the algorithm.

In other words: FLANN is much faster than BFMatcher but it only finds an approximate nearest neighbor, which is a good matching but not necessarily the best. You can play with the parameters of FLANN in order to increase its speed or its precision.

Comment: How big should the database be to make BFMather to slow? If you have a list of 1000 descriptors? more, less?

Answer (score 15):

To add to the above answer, [FLANN](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/research/flann/) builds an efficient data structure (KD-Tree) that will be used to search for an approximate neighbour, while [cv::BFMatcher](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_descriptor_matchers.html#BFMatcher%20:%20public%20DescriptorMatcher) does an exhaustive search and is guaranteed to find the best neighbour. The real benefit of FLANN is seen with large data sets. In my experience, I've seen a *justifiable* benefit is the number of descriptors is larger than 1K.

Comment: Could you please update the [FLANN](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/research/flann/) link? It seems dead. Thanks in advance!