# How does BruteForceMatcher work in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

For example, i have a set of points as template, and three sets of points as target. Now I use BruteForceMatcher to find out that the best match with template points.

But how does BruteForceMatcher wor? Does it work like this?

```
Template Points{Point(x1,y1),Point(x2,y2)....} 
Target Point1{Point(x11,y11),Point(x12,y12)....}
Target Point2{Point(x21,y21),Point(x22,y22)....}
Target Point3{Point(x31,y31),Point(x32,y32)....}

Calculate L2 distant.

d1 = sqrt((x1-x11)^2+(y1-y11)^2) + sqrt((x2-x12)^2+(y2-y12)^2) +...
d2 = sqrt((x1-x21)^2+(y1-y21)^2) + sqrt((x2-x22)^2+(y2-y22)^2) +...
d3 = sqrt((x1-x31)^2+(y1-y31)^2) + sqrt((x2-x32)^2+(y2-y32)^2) +...

Find the minimum d of three, and it's the best match!
```

Does BruteForceMatcher work like this? 
And how about FlannBasedMatcher? 
Can someone help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between BFMatcher and FlannBasedMatcher](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610966/difference-between-bfmatcher-and-flannbasedmatcher)

Comment: Sorry, But i want to how  does BruteForceMatcher work in OpenCV?Not the different

Comment: Just computes the norm for each pair of query and train descriptors. If `normType = NORM_L2` then is exactly as you wrote.

Comment: To get the best match you need to sort in descending order the `vector<DMatch>` outputted by the match function